# Resource Path Location fail find jar was cached in the local repo, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval has elapsed or up

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-boot, maven-plugin

I have setup Spring tool suite with maven plugin and have maven 3.6.1 installed.
I had set the correct settings.xml in the .m2 directory of my home folder(Windows)
First time I created a spring boot starter project it got created and to get all the dependencies in place I did the following :-

```
Right click on project -> Maven -> Update Project -> Force update of snapshots(checked) [1]
```

First time all my dependencies got downloaded in .m2/repository folder and when I ran my project as a spring boot project, it ran successfully.

But when I created a second spring starter project in the same workspace and tried the above mentioned in [1], I got the below error :-

```
Failure to find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE in http://some.domain/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced [2]
```

I have been facing issue mentioned in [2].

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the spring starter project with pom.xml as follows:-

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

But my local maven repo was 2.1.4

So changed

```
<version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
```

To

```
<version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
```

And the issue got resolved